# Disable CRM 2011 Form Assistant for a Single Field on a Form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

How can the form assistant be disabled (or enabled) for a single field on a form?
The form assistant can be enabled/disabled from Form Properties under the Display tab,
 or
the form XML can be altered:

```
 <form enablerelatedinformation="false">
```

or this *unsupported* JavaScript:

```
 document.getElementById('tdRelatedInformationPane').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: It sounds like you answered your own question.  There isn't any supported way to do it, so if you really need it then you probably want to just add focus/lostfocus handlers for the fields you want.

Comment: I was hoping for a supported, best practice, way; seems to be none though. Focus/lostfocus are not supported are they?

Comment: You are correct, those events aren't supported either. Any way you end up going about doing it will be unsupported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is possible to disable the form assistant for a single field, is necessary to remove the corresponding option

```js
var name = "contractid";
var field = document.getElementById(name + "_context");
field.parentNode.removeChild(field);
```

I just blogged a more usable javascript function here:

[Disable CRM 2011 Form Assistant for selected fields](http://www.crmanswers.net/2013/04/disable-crm-2011-form-assistant-for.html)

note: **is an unsupported customization**